# Am i disposing my ODBCConnection

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, using

I'm using a helper method like this:

```
    private OdbcCommand GetCommand(string sql)
    {
        string conString = "blah";
        var con = new OdbcConnection(conString);
        var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, con);
        return cmd;
    }
```

Then i use it like this:

```
using (var cmd = GetCommand("select * from myTable")
{
    cmd.connection.open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
    }
}
```

Here is a second example:

```
    public static OdbcDataReader GetReader(string conString,string sql)
    {
        var cmd = GetCommand(conString, sql);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

used like this:

```
     using(var reader = GetReader("blah","select * from blah")
    {
    }
```

---

In these two cases, am i disposing of the connection and cmd objects? I think connection is not being disposed in the first, and neither connection nor cmd in the second, is that right?

Do i need to do i the long way to ensure correct disposal, or is there a shorter approach?

```
using (var con ...)
    using (var cmd)
        using (var reader)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both examples where you wrap your Reader in a using block, you will close the connection with the existing code IF you use the override that accepts a CommandBehavior and set it to 'CloseConnection'

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)){}
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9bz2k02.aspx

Microsoft knows that the connection must remain open while the reader is consumed, and therefore created the option to close the connection when the Reader is closed.

You are correct that the command is not being Disposed in the second example.

Comment: @Paul - MSDN claims the two are "functionally equivalent." [DbConnection.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.close.aspx)

Comment: @Paul - (cont'd) That said, any provider is required to implement Close on IDbConnection and could do it differently. I believe the whole point of a Connection is that it is an unmanaged resource, probably at some level connected with hardware, so the concept of 'releasing' or 'closing' is more appropriate than, say an object on the heap to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 8):

In short, if it has `Dispose`, then you should call it.  You can't assume that another object will dispose of an object you pass it for you.

Disposing the command object, will not dispose the connection object, because you can use the connection again after you are done with the command.  Disposing of each is the best approach.

Comment: +1, for me also last option with 3x `using...` is most convincing. I use it also in my projects, unless I don't need connection to be reused, like couple commands in one transaction.